# How to close as exact duplicate of a (closed) question without an answer

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I tried to close this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268985/letter-within-a-word-strings-and-lists-returning-counts

as an exact duplicate of this

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17268204/check-if-each-word-has-an-e-in-it

but I can't because it "doesn't have an upvoted/accepted answer"

This seems a bit silly when it literally *is an exact duplicate*!

Comment: One option would be to flag for moderation attention and point to the duplicate.

Comment: Both questions do not fit Stack Overflow. Both should be closed and deleted, so duplicate isn't relevant.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, right, but what about the case when the question _is_ a good fit, and 2 or 3 people ask the exact same question in an hour. We have to wait for one question to be answered before the others can be linked as duplicates - or else flag the mods

Comment: Yep in such case flag is the proper way. By the way, in your example both users are most likely the same person.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all both are already closed as NARQ. When you find a question as a duplicate of another one and another one does not have any answer/good answer while the first one has answer/better answer then you may close the older one as a duplicate of the newer question. However if you can't close the question due to lack of upvoted/accepted answer you can flag for a moderator's attention to do so.

Comment: Flagging a mod is ok as a workaround, but this feels like something the community should be able to be trusted to do without bothering the mods even if the other question doesn't have an answer. Perhaps it's rare enough not to matter.